# why load() event does not detect the div load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

According jquery specification `load()` is the last function that gets called in the **page load**. but when i have several **inner partial pages** and if i place a `<div>` in one of the **inner partials** the `load()` gets executed but if i add a condition check if `div` loaded

```
if ($('#div1').length > 0 ){ }
```

this becomes `false`, why this happens and how to fix?

i check for div1 in the main partial

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#div1').append('<p>this is eg</p>');
    if ($('#div1').length == 0) {
        alert('loaded');
    }
});
```

the above code displays the alert because there is no div but when i check the elements in the chrome it shows an empty div

Comment: can you please provide the code where you are calling `if (('#div1').length > 0 ){ }`

Comment: `jQuery.load()` is a shorthand for the `.ajax()` function. It has nothing to do with when the page is loaded. Assume you mean `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke if thats teh case then how would i check if #div1 is loaded

Comment: I'll just note that `('#div1').length > 0` will **always** be `true`, because you're getting the length of the string `'#div'`. Presumably your real code has a `$`, e.g. `$('#div1').length > 0`?

Comment: `if ($('#div1).length > 0) { // do something }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke it returns false

Comment: Which means that it does not exist in the DOM at the time you call it :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have udpated my post

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i ahev updated my post

Comment: Not sure what you trying to do with that code. Do you have an element with `id="div1"`? (other wise `$('#div1').append('<p>this is eg</p>');` would fail). And `.length` gets the number of elements with `id="div1"`, not the length of its contents.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes there is an element and after page load and do an inspect it shows on element list with data but without my append and the alert()

Comment: @StephenMuecke question is why it shows my div on element list without my append or alert

Comment: @StephenMuecke i wish could put some code but not possible with policies

Comment: @abbatat: Because, clearly, the div isn't there when the `load` event fires, it's being added later, by some asynchronous loading mechanism. The `load` event just waits for elements defined by the HTML itself, not anything loaded with ajax. We can't help you with *why* without more information, ideally an [MCVE](/help/mcve). And its **always possible**, it just takes a bit of effort to create something you can share.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your saying. Firstly, use `$(document).ready(function() { $('#div1').append('<p>this is eg</p>'); ... });` If an element with `id="div1"` exists when the page is first loaded, then the `<p>` element will be added.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: If it's not there for window `load`, it certainly won't be there for jQuery's `ready`, which is *much* earlier.

Comment: @StephenMuecke the who page load is done through a custom written js function so i cannot call load() from it becuase the load must be called outside of all functions,am i correct? If thats teh case then how do i execute the load function to check if the div has loaded

Comment: Without seeing your code, its impossible to tell. I'm guessing that your dynamically loading the element using ajax, so then you can check in the success callback of the ajax function

Comment: @StephenMuecke not it s not a dyamic call i have hard coded the div element in one of the inner partials

Comment: Then the code will work. If its not, there is something you have not shown us that is the issue.

Comment: @StephenMuecke the second option i have is to write scripts in that inner partial. The reason that i need to access this div is im placing jstree control init, the tree will be loaded iwth XML data comes from a server

Comment: Without seeing your code, no one can help.

Comment: @StephenMuecke what i actually do is there is an inner partail called _SHTPartial that has a devexpress treeview control bound with XML data. What i need to do is to remove this devexpress treeview control and add jstree control for this i need to remove devexpress code and put a div, to that div i need to load a jstree control with XML data

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to get #div1 control after page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#div1').append('<p>this is eg</p>');
     if ($('#div1').length == 0) {
          alert('loaded');
     }
});
```

Comment: yes, but in the elements (chrome) it shows but it does not hit my alert or display appended text

Comment: $(window).on('load', function () {

    alert('fired');
    $('#Div1').append('<p>this is eg</p>');
    if ($('#Div1').length >0) {
        alert('loaded');
    }
    else
        alert('not done');
});

 above code is working as expected